# How to easily pass data from child to root in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a comment box like this:

[image]

I have bound all actions to CommentBox component, there is a decComment action to handle `Delete` event in each comment.

Everytime when i click the `delete` button in `Comment` I need to pass the `commentId` of `Comment` to `CommentList` to `CommentBox` and then `CommentBox` updates comment data, removes that comment from comments data and re-renders the comment list.

**Here is some code:**

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
    handleDel: function() {
        var cid = this.props.cid;
        this.props.onDel(cid);
        return false;
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div key={this.props.cid}>
              <a onClick={this.handleDel}>Del</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var CommentList = React.createClass({
    handleDel: function(cid) {
        this.props.onDel(cid);
    },

    render: function() {
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(c) {
            return <Comment cid={c.id} onDel={this.handleDel} />
        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <div className="comments">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        )
    }
});


var CommentBox = React.createClass({

    ... ...

    delComment: function (cid){
        function del(data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'delete',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function (e) {
                    if (e.retcode === 0) {
                        that.setState({
                            data: e.data
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert(e.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        if (window.confirm('You Sure ？')) {
            del();
        }
    },

    ... ...

})
```

This process too verbose!  Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Why is this "too verbose"? In each component you can rename the handler to what is appropriate for the component: in Comment you are handling a "click", but outside that component the notion of a click is irrelevant. In CommentList you're looking for a "delete" with "onDel". Stick with this and see what you think when you come back to the code in a month. I have found this approach more descriptive than having a bunch of listeners on `document.body`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do a partial application of the a handler, like so:

```
<Comment onDel={this.handleDel.bind(null, c.id)} />
```

When `this.handleDel` is called, `c.id` will be passed as the first argument. You can also shorten it by removing `CommentList.handleDel` and just doing

```
<Comment onDel={this.props.onDel.bind(null, c.id)} />
```

For a little more info on this topic, see [Communicate Between Components](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) in the React docs.

Comment: Can we not attach a click handler using React on the top level CommentBox component and listen to any clicks from the Comment component without having to pass the clickHandler all the way down from the CommentBox to CommentList and then to Comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to manage a global application state that will be available to all components, passed by props.

On every change to the application state, you can re-render the whole thing.
As you rerender from the top-level component you may try to optimize with `shouldComponentUpdate`. I didn't test that and don't know if it is manageable for a large application however.

Also, take a look at how [Om](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/12/17/the-future-of-javascript-mvcs/) is optimizing `shouldComponentUpdate` by using immutable data structures.